# Workflow Management for Job Shop - Mobile & Desktop

Tags: database, mobile, workflow, business-intelligence

I'm looking for a database solution to capture workflow tasks, which can be used on desktops (Windows) and also on android and iOS devices. Smoothness of the interface is very important to me, especially where users will do most of their data entry.

I have pretty specific requirements for the data schema, so a database platform that I can customize & program on seems most likely, but if there's an off-the-shelf solution that matches this, that would work too. So far the leading contender is salesforce.com, but it looks hard to make the end user interface not clunky.

My specific goals:

- Be able to generate work orders with specific task lists (where each task is assigned to an individual) and purchase requests (where request doesn't have to be from a BOM)
- Be able to keep a list of outstanding tasks for each individual, with feedback when complete
- Be able to keep a list of outstanding purchases, with feedback when recieved
- Have the option to create recurring tasks on various schedules
- There are other requirements, but they are less specific and most ERP software seems to have them baked-in.

Is there any product that would accomplish this well, with or without custom code?